# Colorize a 3D plot with given function of dependent variable and add a bar legend

Tags: plotting, functions, color

I want to colorize a surface $u(t,x,y)$ generated by `Plot3D` with a given function of $u$. For example,

```
L = 4;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], t, t] == 
D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + Sin[u[t, x, y]], 
u[t, -L, y] == u[t, L, y], u[t, x, -L] == u[t, x, L], 
u[0, x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], 
Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0}, 
u, {t, 0, L/2}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}]
```

The colorized function reads:

```
f[u_] := 1/(u[t, x, y] + 0.2);
```

As suggested by J.M., I plotted with

```
Plot3D[u[L/2, x, y] /. First[sol], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow", 0.1/(z + 0.1)]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None, LegendMarkers -> 200]]
```

which gives the following figure, but the Legend does not appear...

[image]

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you seen `ColorFunctionScaling`?

Comment: @J.M. Thank for your information. Just learn the usage of `ColorFunctionScaling` however, I want to use the original scale and range, calculated from `f[u_]`, instead of scaling the color to lie between 0 and 1.

Comment: So, `Plot3D[u[L/2, x, y] /. First[sol], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap", 1/(z + 0.2)]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`?

Comment: @J.M. It works. Thanks. But I also want to add a Legend with `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, None, LegendMarkers -> 200]`. But the Legend does not appear aside the 3D plot. In my real problem the variation in the color looks very small even with `ColorFunctionScaling->True`. Could you suggest a color scheme or some trick to emphasize the variation. You could write it as an answer and I will accept it. If you will :)

Comment: "But I also want to add a Legend" - that's quite different from what you asked, no?

Comment: @J.M. sorry...please see the update :)